# scaling factor to match curves with least deviation

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization

I have sets of curves whose shapes are different than my target curve. I am trying to match these curves with the target curve by multiplying their amplitude with a scale factor. I need only one optimum scale factor so that my data follows the shape of the target with least deviation in a specified range. Should I use multiobjective optimization for this case or are there any better algorithms available?

Here is my sample vector arrays for the data and target curve:

```
x=[ 0.1000  0.1072  0.1149  0.1232  0.1320  0.1415  0.1517  0.1626  0.1742...
     0.1868  0.2002  0.2146  0.2300  0.2465 0.2643  0.2833  0.3036  0.3254...
      0.3488 0.3739  0.4008  0.4296  0.4605]

data=[0.6080 0.6413 0.668 0.6888 0.6923  0.6490 0.6018 0.6461  0.6862  0.6519 0.7454...
    0.9117 0.9508 0.8383 0.6244 0.5010 0.4517 0.4484 0.4131 0.3792 0.3502 0.3300 0.3235]


target=[0.8666 0.8810 0.9026 0.9275 0.9542 0.9828 1.0120 1.0342 1.0578 1.0829 1.1096...
   1.1411 1.1749 1.2110 1.2413 1.2713 1.2955 1.2955 1.2817 1.2659 1.2618 1.2559 1.2034]
```

If I want to match amplitudes at x=0.2, I simply divide the amplitudes of curves at this point to find scale factor then multiply data with this factor, but the shape of the scaled curve results in large deviations wrt target for other range of x values. Actually, I could not figure out  how to find optimum scale factor that fits well at x=0.2 as well as scaled data curve follows the target with least deviation. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your existing code/attempts so that users can see what you have done so far.

Comment: where are you getting target data?

Comment: Target can be expressed as a theoretical representation of the problem It generally follows smoother trend rather than experimental data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`fminbnd`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/fminbnd.html). Its first argument is a handle to the function to be minimized. That function should be your "deviation", which depends on the optimization parameter, in this case `scale`.

You need to specify your optimization criterion (that is, how you define "deviation"). I suggest you use [`norm`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/norm.html) for that. The second argument to `norm` indicates which norm you use. Setting it to `2` corresponds to minimizing square error. See the doc (link above) for other options.

```
optScale = fminbnd(@(scale) norm(scale*data-target, 2), .1, 10);
```

With your example data and 2-norm criterion, the optimum scale (which minimizes square error between the curves) is

```
>> optScale = fminbnd(@(scale) norm(scale*data-target, 2), .1, 10)
optScale =
    1.6921
```

Comment: This function works perfectly for my example case. I think 2-norm of vector arrays returns to sum of square error for the entire range of my data. But when I use logarithmic values of two curves optimum scale factor does not converge to correct answer? I would like to ask one more question regarding two-criteria optimization. My another objective is to obtain best match for the average of N scaled data curves with the target while optimizing the deviation of individual curves. Is there any way to combine both these objectives in the optimization process?

Comment: @user3087937 I don't get what you mean about the logarithmic values. sorry

Comment: @user3087937 If you have N data curves, and each has its own scale factor, then you should optimize each scaling factor independently of all the others... right?

Comment: I mean I tried natural logarithm of each points by taking log(data) and log(target) for the square error calculation which ends up with different results.

Comment: @user3087937 Well, that's perfectly natural. Minimizing the mean square error is not the same as minimizing the mean square error of the logs